# If Statement not passing a test case

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hello I am working on a codefights challenge, I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this issue, All of my test cases pass that i am given, I also have 4 hidden test cases that i need to pass, However I am passing all but one of the hidden test cases. My brain is completely racked, I have created all my own test cases i can possibly think of and all of them pass just fine. It is just this one hidden case, i have tried type checking everything seems to be checking out.

> n children have got m pieces of candy. They want to eat as much candy as
>   they can, but each child must eat exactly the same amount of candy as  any > other child. Determine how many pieces of candy will be eaten by all the
>   children together. Individual pieces of candy cannot be split.
>
> **Example**
>
> For n = 3 and m = 10, the output should be
>      candies(n, m) = 9.
>
> Each child will eat 3 pieces. So the answer is 9.
>
> **Input/Output**
>
> [time limit] 4000ms (js)
>
> [input] integer n
>
> **The number of children.**
>
> Constraints:
>      1 ≤ n ≤ 10.
>
> [input] integer m
>
> **The number of pieces of candy.**
>
> Constraints:
>      2 ≤ m ≤ 100.
>
> [output] integer
>
> The total number of pieces of candy the children will eat provided they 
>   eat as much as they can and all children eat the same amount.

**Code**

```js
function candies(n, m) {
  if ((n > 10 || n < 1) || (m > 100 || m < 2)) {
    return 0;
  } else if (n > m) {
    return 0;
  } else if (n === m) {
    return m;
  } else if (n < m) {
    var candyKids = Math.round(m / n);
    return candyKids * n;
  };
};
```

Comment: This would fit more on the puzzle section.

Comment: Try `candies(4, 7)`.

Comment: @Lain Sorry i disagree, as this is javascript and i am trying to find a solution to my problem. Also i am providing an answer ( even if it is partial).

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, working on the remainder now.

Comment: @CASEY BAILEY: That is totally okay. Opinions differ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some test cases that will fail with your code:

```
candies( 2, 3 ) === 2 (Your output: 4)
candies( 2, 5 ) === 4 (Your output: 6)
candies( 3, 5 ) === 3 (Your output: 6)
candies( 4, 7 ) === 4 (Your output: 8)
```

**Where was the error?**

You are using `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`, what that means is that you will round up partial candies that are greater than half after dividing amongst the children, so for `candies( 2, 3 )`, you determine that that are `m/n = 1.5` candies per child, then you round it and allocate `2` candies to each child, but that creates more candy than you have to begin with. In cases like this you need to floor instead (always round partial candies down) and only give `1` candy to each child.

Comment: Thank you, so i need to deal with the remainder. You can go ahead and post what is wrong i will fix mine then come back and compare.

Comment: Or simply `function candies(n, m) { return m - m % n; }`.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, however I don't think that helps the OP much with their current attempt.